# Can I bypass ADFS for a single URL?

Tags: c#, windows, service, single-sign-on, adfs

I've created a service that POSTs to a WEB API when it finds certain values in a database that it is querying every 3 minutes. The POST then causes a signal-R push to our intranet site in order to alert everyone using the site at the time.
However, our site is secured by ADFS and consequently the POST from the service cannot be done in a simple manner. I'm looking up 'ActAs' and trying to get that working on the service, but it has also been suggested to me that perhaps a single site can be exempted from the ADFS redirect hop in the web.config. It is an internal site so exempting one or more urls from ADFS for purposes of POSTing would make things a lot easier.

Is this possible and if so, how?